# pd.read_table for .dat fills null values

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am trying to learn data analysis using "Python for Data analysis" by WesMcKinney.

There is a `.dat` file with the following data :

```
1::F::1::10::48067
2::M::56::16::70072
3::M::25::15::55117
4::M::45::7::02460
```

I'm trying to import them using :

```
unames=['user_id', 'gender', 'age', 'occupation', 'zip']
users = pd.read_table('D:/INSOFE/Python_practice/users.dat', sep='::', header=None,names=unames,engine='python')
```

But, it shows nulls

[image]

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can't reproduce, when I create the `.dat` file as you provide, and load it via your exact `pd.read_table`, it looks fine on my computer. Perhaps check your path to you `users.dat`, and make sure it's a valid file?

Comment: Could you copy paste the code before `unames` definition?

Comment: It looks like you might have obtained the dat file from a web page, but rather than save the contents of the page, you have saved the page itself (including a bunch of HTML). Could that be it? Try opening the file to see what it contains.

Comment: @sacul : the file path and file both are valid.

Comment: @fuglede : yes, I've opened the file in notepad, it contained the html in it too. https://github.com/wesm/pydata-book/blob/1st-edition/ch02/movielens/users.dat  ,I got it, I will try downloading only the data. I thought .dat files contain html too.

Comment: @fuglede : yes, it worked. Thank you so much for figuring it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) method expects relatively clean data; if you've simply saved the [web page containing the table](https://github.com/wesm/pydata-book/blob/1st-edition/ch02/movielens/users.dat) (cf. the clarifying comments), you will end up with a file full of HTML which pandas will not know what to do about.

Instead, you will want to get the raw contents of the file. In principle you could simply copy the 6040 lines from GitHub into your favorite text editor and save the contents as `users.dat`.

GitHub makes your life a bit simpler than that by supplying a view of the [raw data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/1st-edition/ch02/movielens/users.dat) as well.

[image: How to view "Raw" data in GitHub]

With that, if you choose to save the file, most browsers (including e.g. Firefox) will produce a proper `users.dat` with only the data. Command line tools such as [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) allow you to get at the same data without having to use a fully-fledged browser.

Comment: yes, you are correct :)..I have downloaded the entire zip folder of the book's code to avoid this confusion. Thanks a lot.